# Unable to create sharing rules on custom object

Tags: sharing-rule

I am unable to create sharing rule for any custom object on my app. 
I have checked the following:

1. The user has system administrator privileges
2. The app has sharing option checked
3. The object is not a part of any master-detail relationship

Attaching the screenshot for reference.
Please help me in figuring out why defining sharing rule is not enabled.

[Sharing rule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PltUK.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a screenshot of Job Application object ?

Comment: Can you check deployment status of `Job Application` object is set to `Deployed`

Comment: are you Professional edition?